# Converting to 13 digit timestamp in c#

Tags: c#

I am currently stuck at a problem. I hope someone can solve it.

I have a timestamp like this: 27/Jun/2020 09:40:50:200 (dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff)

I want to convert it into the 13 digit timestamp using c#.

What I was doing previously:

given input: 6/26/2020 4:09:51 +00:00

output: 1593187791355

Comment: Well, you really have o tell us what a 13 digit timestamp is supposed to be anyd why you do not just foramt it using a custom format string. Also, timestamps (DateTime) instances do NOT have a format. They are a floating number, internally.

Comment: Kindly provide a sample of 13 digit timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

you probably mean the Unix ticks since 1970 which is represented in .NET by .ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()

```
    string date = "27/Jun/2020 09:40:50.120";
    
    var pdate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(date);
    var unixTimeMilliseconds = pdate.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(unixTimeMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine(unixTimeMilliseconds.Lenght);
```

gives you:

1593243650120

13

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Actually my device will be giving me 5 values in 1 second. So I want to also take milliseconds in account.

Comment: @anandkumarPanigrahi If the original date has miliseconds, the output will also include the milliseconds. Have you tried it? What exactly is the problem? You can test it using something like `new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()`.

Comment: Thanks @AhmedAbdelhameed, I have solved my problem. Also  deleted the duplicated question

Comment: @anandkumarPanigrahi modified the answer to reflext milliseconds in the input